# How to save an empty data to adlsgen2 using R?

Tags: r, azure-data-lake, sparkr, azure-data-lake-gen2

I've explored but didn't find any suggestions.
I want to know how to save an empty file to adlsgen2 using R and then read it back to the same code.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks like you're fairly new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample code you've attempted, listing non-base R packages, any errors/warnings received, sample data, like the output from `dput(head(dataObject)))`, and what type of output you are expecting. Check it out: [making R questions reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to write an empty file to ADLS gen2 using R and read it from that location, first create a dataframe.

- The dataframe can either be completely empty, or it can be a dataframe with column names but no rows. You can use the following code to create one.

```
df <- data.frame()  #OR

df <- data.frame(<col_name>=<type>)
```

- Once you have created a dataframe, you must establish connection to ADLS gen2 account. You can use the method specified in the following link to do that.

https://saketbi.wordpress.com/2019/05/11/how-to-connect-to-adls-gen2-using-sparkr-from-databricks-rstudio-while-integrating-securely-with-azure-key-vault/

- After making the connection you can use read and write functions in R language using the path to ADLS gen2 storage. The following link provides numerous functions that can be used according to your requirement.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-files-in-r-programming/

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the solution to my question:

I've used SparkR to create an empty data frame and save the same in the adls after setting up the spark context.

Solution is below:

Step 1: Create a schema

```
fcstSchema <- structType(structField("ABC", "string",TRUE))

new_df<- data.frame(ABC=NULL,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

n<-createDataFrame(new_df,fcstSchema)

SparkR::saveDF(n,path = "abfss://<account_name>@<datalake>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path>/",source = "delta",mode = "overwrite")
```